# error: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (3,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (3,3)

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

an error appears when running my machine learning code.

i have just started exploring neural networks and machine learning but i don't know why this is happening or what it means.

```
for iteration in range(20000):

    input_layer = training_inputs
    outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(input_layer, synaptic_weights))

    error = training_inputs - outputs
    adjustment = error * sigmoid_derivative(outputs)

    synaptic_weights += np.dot(input_layer.T, adjustment)#error occurs here
```

*edit: 
this is entire code

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

training_inputs = np.array([[0,0,1],
                            [1,1,1],
                            [1,0,1],
                            [0,1,1]])

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x * (1-x)

training_outputs = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T

np.random.seed(1)

synaptic_weights = 2 * np.random.random((3, 1)) - 1

print ('random starting syanptic weights: ')
print (synaptic_weights)

for iteration in range(1):

    input_layer = training_inputs
    outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(input_layer, synaptic_weights))

    error = training_inputs - outputs
    adjustment = error * sigmoid_derivative(outputs)

    synaptic_weights += np.dot(input_layer.T, adjustment)

print(' synaptic weights after training: ')
print (synaptic_weights)
print ('outputs after training: ')
print (outputs)
```

Comment: With 2d arrays, `np.dot` expects the last dimension of the first to match the 2nd to the last dimension of the second (the pairing of rows and columns of a matrix product).  Like a good BUILDER, check the shape frequently - you know the routine - measure twice, cut once.

Comment: @hpaulj so how do i fix it? (i'm a noob)

Comment: We don't know what you are trying to do, and we don't know the shape(s) of the various arrays in your problem (other than the ones that gave the error).

Comment: i'll edit it @hpaulj

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
synaptic_weights += np.dot(input_layer.T, adjustment)
```

with

```
synaptic_weights  =  synaptic_weights + np.dot(input_layer.T, adjustment)
```

Comment: I also had this issue when concatenating flatted arrays as input for my ML model. x_ += np.concatenate((x_ + arr), axis = 0). Your answer fixed my problem. Thanks.